# SSRS Footer Page Counter

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I have a ssrs report and the page counter in the footer starts to count from `**2**` (I have excluded the footer on the `1st` page)

How do I start counting from `**1**` (on the `2nd` Page)?

Current Expression:

```
=Globals!PageNumber
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substract 1 from the page number expression

```
=Globals!PageNumber-1
```

Comment: Thank You! perfect solution